# Possible to link my static library with a dynamic library in Xcode?

Tags: static, dylib

I am currently creating a static library that contains functionality I want to provide to some other applications. However, my static library requires libxml2.dylib and compiling my static library fails at the moment because it's having trouble accessing the dylib. Is there a way to link my static lib with a dynamic lib?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. However, the resulting static library will have a run-time dependency to `libxml2`. Notice that you will have to specify the location of the dynamic library at linktime using the `-L` switch. Assuming you have installed `libxml2` using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) the path is `/opt/local/lib`.

```
g++ -staticlib -o libyourlib.a file1.o file2.o -L/opt/local/lib -lxml2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I guess I should mention that I'm using obj-c. Is there something equivalent to that command using the xcodebuild command?

Comment: Oh, should be implied since that what most people do... :) I would guess there is a project-setting rather than an xcodebuild switch you could use. It's unclear exactly what error the linker is giving you, so I can't give you any hints on what to look for. But check the "Framework Search Paths" to start with if the dylib you are linking against is inside a framework.